# How to align two hyperplanes with plane equations

Tags: python, matplotlib, transformation

I am trying to Euclidean transform one plane to other plane. I have two equation of planes and they have different sizes. How can I align two planes in one coordinate system?

My two planes in form of ax+by+cz+d=0.

first plane => a = -5.297742252442251, b = 21.751836101364013, c = -2.470896764133499, d = -0.5601826186620921

Second plane => a = 45.42557999642176, b = -16.9433283673388, c = 2.5117971500097287, d = -8.528560240570203]

For plotting on the matplotlib, I used following code using matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as LDA
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
from skimage import measure
import pandas as pd

# Data points 1 and 2
data1 = [[0.190133571624755, 0.146549582481384, 0.391435742378234, 'near'], 
     [0.0154470205307006, 0.0959569215774536, 0.484999418258667, 'near'], 
     [-0.119875073432922, 0.0414541959762573, 0.542818903923034, 'near'],
     [0.104917883872985, 0.058539867401123, 0.171926498413085, 'far'],
     [0.177520513534545, 0.130982756614685, 0.0330302715301513, 'far'],
     [0.246979117393493, 0.173633933067321, 0.373323440551757, 'far']]

data2 = [[0.334545135498046, -0.0318257808685302, 0.282101511955261, 'near'], 
     [0.411889553070068, 0.0223467350006103, 0.183727979660034, 'near'], 
     [0.330880641937255, -0.00959080457687378, 0.178299665451049, 'near'],
     [-0.00756144523620605, -0.07442307472229, -0.227764248847961, 'far'],
     [-0.268512785434722, -0.309048891067504, 0.456292867660522, 'far'],
     [-0.305409669876098, -0.304299354553222, 0.281461238861084, 'far']]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'NearOrFar'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'NearOrFar'])

# Data - 1 
# Divide into X and y
X1 = df1.iloc[:,0:3]
Y1 = df1.iloc[:,3]

# Create scatter plot of data points for data 1
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
for grp_name, grp_idx in df1.groupby('NearOrFar').groups.items():
    x = df1.iloc[grp_idx, 0]
    y = df1.iloc[grp_idx, 1]
    z = df1.iloc[grp_idx, 2]
    if (grp_name == 'near'):
        ax.scatter(x, y, z, label=grp_name, c = 'red')
    else:
        ax.scatter(x, y, z, label=grp_name, c = 'blue')

# Train LDA model for data 1
lda_clf_1 = LDA(store_covariance=True)
lda_clf_1.fit(X1, Y1)

# Decision boundary Coefficient
a,b,c,d = lda_clf_1.coef_[0][0],lda_clf_1.coef_[0] [1],lda_clf_1.coef_[0][2],lda_clf_1.intercept_

# Find limit of each coordinates
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ylim = ax.get_ylim()

# Create meshgrid in xyz
xx = np.linspace(xlim[0], xlim[1], 50)
yy = np.linspace(ylim[0], ylim[1], 50)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xx,yy)
Z = (-d - a*X - b*Y) / c

# plot decision boundary hyperplane
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, alpha=0.45)
plt.show()

# Data - 2
# Divide into X and y
X2 = df2.iloc[:,0:3]
Y2 = df2.iloc[:,3]


# Create scatter plot of data points for data 2
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
for grp_name, grp_idx in df2.groupby('NearOrFar').groups.items():
    x = df2.iloc[grp_idx, 0]
    y = df2.iloc[grp_idx, 1]
    z = df2.iloc[grp_idx, 2]
    if (grp_name == 'near'):
        ax.scatter(x, y, z, label=grp_name, c = 'red')
    else:
        ax.scatter(x, y, z, label=grp_name, c = 'blue')

# Train LDA model for data 2
lda_clf_2 = LDA(store_covariance=True)
lda_clf_2.fit(X2, Y2)

# Decision boundary Coefficient
a,b,c,d = lda_clf_2.coef_[0][0],lda_clf_2.coef_[0][1],lda_clf_2.coef_[0][2],lda_clf_2.intercept_

# Find limit of each coordinates
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ylim = ax.get_ylim()

# Create meshgrid in xyz
xx = np.linspace(xlim[0], xlim[1], 50)
yy = np.linspace(ylim[0], ylim[1], 50)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xx,yy)
Z = (-d - a*X - b*Y) / c

# plot decision boundary hyperplane
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, alpha=0.45)
plt.show()
```

How can I align two planes and create 3d plot of two align planes in one graph with data points?

At the end, I want to transform(mostly roatation I think?) all the data points on data2 to coordinate system of data1 as data2 hyperplane align with data1 hyperplane

Each datapoints with hyperplane should looks like following

Data 1 =
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0mNV.png)

and
Data 2 = [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TypxU.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to plot the two planes on the same 3d axes, then you just need to compute two different values for `Z` and plot the two `Z`s relative to the same `X`s and `Y`s, like so:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# first plane:

a1 = -5.297742252442251
b1 = 21.751836101364013
c1 = -2.470896764133499
d1 = -0.5601826186620921

# second plane:

a2 = 45.42557999642176
b2 = -16.9433283673388
c2 = 2.5117971500097287
d2 = -8.528560240570203

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = (-d1 - a1 * X - b1 * Y) / c1
Z2 = (-d2 - a2 * X - b2 * Y) / c2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z1, alpha=0.45)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z2, alpha=0.45)
plt.show()
```

This produces the following figure:

[image]

As to "aligning" the two planes, it's not clear to me what you're asking...? Two planes will be coplanar if they have the same values of a, b, c and d in the equation you gave above - if they have different values of a, b, c and d, they won't be coplanar. They may intersect, they may not - and to ensure you graph them where they intersect (should they do so), you'd need to determine the values of x and y where they have equal values of z and set your xrange and yrange accordingly. If you can explain the meaning of "align" for your particular purposes, perhaps I could expand on this answer to accommodate.

Comment: Oh I was trying to align two hyperplanes which was created from the linear discrimination. So I want to transform all the datapoints on either side of plane as I transform the plane. I edited the question to show datapoints with hyperplane

Comment: Can you lay out your algorithm/process for the "transformation" you speak of? what can you provide example data points? I see you've provided an image - but if you want the code to work with some actual points, please provide those points and a description of what you want done to the points?

Comment: I added some data points in the question. I want to transform one of those two data to where the hyperplane is align in one coordinates system. I want to find out how to transform data points to plane that two hyperplanes are align